# SystemError: error return without exception set

Tags: c++, python-embedding

I'm learning about embedding Python, and in my test program I'm calling Python code from my C application, and then the Python code calls a method I've provided:

```
#include <Python.h>

// The callback function.
extern "C" PyObject * printHello(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    printf("hello from C\n");
    return 0;
}

PyMethodDef methods [] = {
    { "printHello", printHello, METH_NOARGS, "docs docs docs" },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    Py_InitModule("emb", methods);
    PyRun_SimpleString(
                "import emb\n"
                "emb.printHello()\n"
                );
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The program runs and my function is called, but upon returning I get an exception:

```
hello from C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in 
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

I assume this has something to do with the calling convention, or signature of my callback function.

In particular, is it because I'm returning 0? My function doesn't really need to return anything, that's why I return 0. I would have used `void printHello()`, but `PyCFunction` requires the signature to be `PyObject * func(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that your function doesn't really need to return anything (in this case), but, in Python, "not returning anything" means returning `None`. Try replacing

```
return 0;
```

in your `printHello` function with

```
Py_INCREF(Py_None);
return Py_None;
```

The first line increments the refcount of `None`, and the second line returns it.

Even better, just use [`Py_RETURN_NONE`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/none.html) (which is shorthand for the same):

```
extern "C" PyObject * printHello(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    printf("hello from C\n");
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```